# Angular: Using $location.path() instead of href

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I recently began using `$location.path()` within `ng-click` functions rather than simply referencing a path within the `href` of an `a` tag.
My reasons for doing so:

- Preference to have ALL logic, including paths navigated to moved out of my views (this may be a bit extreme).
- For rare instances where multiple html templates reference the same controller I can change `$location.path()` once rather than having to remember to update corresponding href's within each template.

So instead of:

```
<a class="button button-balanced" href="/signup">Sign up</a>
```

I have:

```
<button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="goToSignup()">Sign up</button>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.goToSignup = function() {
    $location.path('/signup');
}
```

My question is, are there drawbacks to setting my Angular app up this way? (note: I'm mainly building Ionic hybrid mobile apps)

Comment: Wrapping a button in a link is kind of bad, rather if you want it to act like a link, then style a link to look like a button.

Comment: I would guess that doing script redirects is bad for seo and usability, compared to using links.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to note an `a` tag styled as a button. SEO isn't a concern since these apps will end up as iOS and Android native apps.

Answer (score 0):

- Preference to have ALL logic, including paths navigated to moved out of my views (this may be a bit extreme).

You can do with your all logic and paths navigated by using **same** link button

```
<a href="/signup" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="SignUpFunc()>Sign Up</a>
```

the a tag is first execute the click function, then execute the href call. So you can do it by link button.

- For rare instances where multiple html templates reference the same controller I can change `$location.path()` once rather than having to remember to update corresponding href's within each template.

If you using menu option, you can use link button
but if you navigate one controller to another controller, then you should use the
`$location.path('/signup');`

Answer (score -1):

I also used similar logic in my project.It works fine for me.

```
<button class="button" ng-click="go('view')">Next Page</button>

    $scope.go = function ( path ) {
        $location.path( path );
    };
```